# sqlite query to search database with multiple keywords

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I used a code similar to the following code to search the database person name :

```
cursor.query(select column from Table where column_person_Name="John");
```

But now I want to search the names of a few people together,How to do it?

Comment: You mean you have a list of names, and you want to get all results that match one of those names?

Comment: @MarkusPenguin oh sorry, I want to search the list of names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do that using SQlite would be using `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name IN ("John", "Doe");
```

In Java, having an array of Strings, you could do it like that:

```
final String[] namesArray = {"John", "Doe"};

// Pad the Strings with quotes: John -> 'John'
for (int i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
    namesArray[i] = "'" + namesArray[i] + "'";
}

// Join the Strings: 'John', 'Doe'
final String names = TextUtils.join(",", namesArray);
final String query = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name IN ("+names+")";
```

This results in:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name IN ('John','Doe')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IN` condition

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE column_person_Name IN ('Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3');
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the OR operator;

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3 ...;
```

here an example;

```
cursor.rawQuery("select column from Table where column_person_Name='John' OR column_person_Name='Bob');
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution for your problem can be,  use `like` Keyword, where you get multiple results based on the `search`.

Like is used across application partial known data.

```
 SELECT
   column_list
FROM
   table_name
WHERE
  column_1 LIKE %yoursearch_word%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Room supports Collections as a query argument.

Query in Room is like:

```
@Query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE region IN (:regions)")
public List<NameTuple> loadUsersFromRegions(List<String> regions);
```

Check [official](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-collection-args)  guides.